# Simulate filling a Box with objects or particles and transport it (100000+ objects)

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

For a science video I try to simulate filling a lot of rice in a box an than remove the box, so the rice can spread out. The pictures below show an example of what I try to achive, but in the example I made the blocks are too big and too few. I try to get something arround 300k to 600k.

Has someone an idea how to do this for example with particles or an addon I do not know or something else?
With rigid body and real objects blender always crashed.

[image: Blocks before they fall]

[image: Blocks afert fall in invisible box]

[image: Blocks spread after removing the invisible box]

Comment: you can try this with the molecular add-on. Another "trick" might be to use a lot less particles, and to "block" unseen things e.g. instead of using 500k particles, use 100k when e.g. filling a truck and hide a big box inside a box - depending on your camera angle.

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea. I will try, which molecular add-on you use for that?

Comment: i am using this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUNuU.png